# Handling records of generic functions

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

Let's define the following type for a handler function:

```
type Handler<T, U> = (x: T) => U;
```

Then say there's a library that takes a dictionary of handlers (which is then used somehow to route data to a specific handler, how is not relevant to the question):

```
registerHandlers(handlers: Record<string, Handler<any, any>>) {
  ...
}
```

This works fine, and I can e.g. pass a literal object to the `registerHandlers` function:

```
registerHandlers({
  foo: (x: number) => 'foo', 
  bar: (x: string) => 42
});
```

However, to make the interface clearer and to allow for easier stubbing and testing of the handlers, I'd like to define an interface that describes my handlers:

```
interface Handlers {
  foo: Handler<number, string>;
  bar: Handler<string, number>;
}
```

This way it's easy to define or override a set of handlers with all types inferred (obviously my example is simpled down, my real code has much more complex types which is why I want to define a clear type for the entire collection of handlers):

```
const handlers: Handlers = {
  foo: x => 'foo',
  bar: x => 42
}
```

However, when I try to use my interface as a `Record<string, Handler<any, any>>` by calling `registerHandlers(handlers)`, it doesn't work, not even if using `as Record<...>` (unless I do double conversion via `unknown` which always seems like the last resort):

```
Index signature is missing in type Handlers
```

My `Handlers` interface clearly is an object with a set of `Handler` functions, so in practice, it should match a `Record` of the same, but it doesn't. I guess I understand why an arbitrary interface cannot be guaranteed to match a `Record`, but is there a nice way of defining a type so that it is a `Record<string, Handler<any, any>>` but still declared as a type where each individual property is a properly typed `Handler<, >`? Or am I stuck with a double conversion via `unknown`, with the risks associated (a simple typo could go unnoticed etc)?

Answer (score 1):

this is a [known issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15300) of interfaces' behavior.

simple workaround would be using type alias instead of interface here, if shouldn't affect your future code, since they are (mostly) interchangeable.

```
type Handlers = {
  foo: Handler<number, string>;
  bar: Handler<string, number>;
}
```

[ts playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAEghgOwCYBsICcA8AVANFAVQD4oBeKACgA8AuKbASjJIIG4AodgMwFcEBjYAEsA9gijoIAcyEBnYBnjI06WRQAWiVBll0AShH4j0STPPRCEU-Eu1ZEIfA6JEmAb3ZQo7AL7f2kjLyiloqah5eXCIidNR0CDwAtgBGGEykJADkUSKZ+J5QyXDosbRQ5pZS6SQALABMvgwc7KCQsKE6ZFARUDl0tiqYCSkY+BVWRBxeRSXtyhhmwBZW+MOp6JO+nEYI8lCa86r9HapdPX1QVMxQ2dF5BTN0VxlQ9VvsO3uzBkYmi8vWOZ2TAOJwIEAuLoHOyyTiBOQKdADHQUdAMIA)

Answer (score 1):

You can work around the problem by re-defining the argument expected by `registerHandler`:

```
type Handler<T, U> = (x: T) => U;

interface Handlers {
  foo: Handler<number, string>;
  bar: Handler<string, number>;
}

const handlers: Handlers = {
  foo: x => 'foo',
  bar: x => 42
}

declare class Foo {
  registerHandlers<T extends string>(handlers: Record<T, Handler<any, any>>): void;
}

new Foo().registerHandlers(handlers);
```

Comment: This indeed works. But I'm not entirely sure why. Would you be able to elaborate why `T extends string` as the `Record` key fulfills an interface type with only string keys, but a pure `Record` of `string` does not?
I also found that using a type alias instead of an interface works. And I found https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15300 which I guess is related, so maybe this is just how it is...

Comment: It's because `Record<string, string>` — contrary to intuition — doesn't mean an object with string properties only. It only means that when such an object has string properties, their values must also be strings. However, such an object is still allowed to have numeric or symbolic properties. Have a look at this: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30993#issuecomment-484166061 and this: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/31014#issuecomment-484570773.

Comment: As for types vs. interfaces — types have implicit index properties. Interfaces require explicit ones.